# Jade image gallery using extends, mixins and includes not working

Tags: include, pug, mixins, image-gallery, photo-gallery

I'm trying to build a Jade image gallery using mixins and includes, but can't get it working. Here's my setup:

**layout-template.jade (the base layout template)**

```
block vars
doctype html
  (head and all it's meta tags)...
block body
      (body content)...
block main-content
      h1 This is the default layout             
block footer
      script(src='/js/min/app-min.js')
```

**image-gallery-page.jade (the page with the image gallery)**

```
extends ../../__JADE/_layout-template.jade

block vars
    - var pageTitle = 'New page title'

block body
    body

block main-content
     (main page content...)

     include ../../__JADE/_include-view-original.jade
     +originalImage('http://placehold.it/800x400', 'Original Image 1')
     +originalImage('http://placehold.it/800x400', 'Original Image 2')
     +originalImage('http://placehold.it/800x400', 'Original Image 3')
```

**image-gallery-include.jade (the include file being pulled into the image-gallery-page, with the mixin)**

```
.row
    .large-10.columns
         .text-center Click for larger view
              .owl-carousel.owl-theme.popup-gallery#owl-carousel-original-article
                   mixin originalImage(originalLink, originalTitle)
                        a(href="#{originalLink}" title="#{originalTitle}")
                            img(src="#{originalLink}")
```

The original images 1-3 from the mixin appear, but not inside the owl-carousel div that I need them to be in. If I indent the mixin under the include, they don't compile.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me personally, I would dedicate a file to my mixins or individual mixins and include them at the top of a file I wish to use them in.

Then you can simply invoke the mixin where necessary.

Currently, you have the following ;

`.row
    .large-10.columns
         .text-center Click for larger view
              .owl-carousel.owl-theme.popup-gallery#owl-carousel-original-article
                   mixin originalImage(originalLink, originalTitle)
                        a(href="#{originalLink}" title="#{originalTitle}")
                            img(src="#{originalLink}")`

But altering to;

`mixin originalImage(originalLink, originalTitle)
    a(href="#{originalLink}" title="#{originalTitle}")
        img(src="#{originalLink}")
.row
    .large-10.columns
         .text-center Click for larger view
              .owl-carousel.owl-theme.popup-gallery#owl-carousel-original-article`

Would make the difference.

However, if you choose to do this, you could do a little shuffling and result with something like;

```
extends ../../__JADE/_layout-template.jade
include ../../__JADE/_mixins.jade

block vars
    - var pageTitle = 'New Page Title'
block body
    body
block main-content
    (main page content...)
    .row
        .large-10.columns
            .text-center Click for larger view
                .owl-carousel.owl-theme.popup-gallery#owl-carousel-original-article
                    +originalImage('http://placehold.it/800x400', 'Original Image 1')
                    +originalImage('http://placehold.it/800x400', 'Original Image 2')
                    +originalImage('http://placehold.it/800x400', 'Original Image 3')
```

Additionally, you could define a map and loop over them to invoke your mixins to save you more code.

Something like the following could potentially work;

```
- var images = ['http://placehold.it/800x400', 'http://placehold.it/800x400', 'http://placehold.it/800x400']
each val, index in images
    +originalImage(val, 'Original Image ' + index)
```

That last bit might need a little tweaking as it's off the top of my head but hopefully that will help you out a little.

I try to separate my Jade files into many manageable modules and pieces so that it's simple to maintain. As your project grows maybe think about having folders for the different markup components. For example, having a folder for different mixins and being able to include specific mixins for different parts of your project.

[@jh3y](https://github.com/jh3y)

Comment: Wow thanks for the suggestions. Will definitely look at splitting up the mixins.

My only concern with putting the .owl-carousel code directly into the page is that sometimes I may not want to use the gallery so can simply delete the include line. But if I do want to include it, I only have to call the mixin with the links at viola. 

Make sense? Is that do-able?

Comment: Well the surrounding code is non-dynamic and always the same so for those instances look to create maybe component snippets.

For example; having component blocks under a `components` folder. Then create a `carousel` component file that makes use of the mixins file. Lastly include it at the appropriate place with something like

`include ../../__JADE/components/carousel`

However, alternatively you could create a new mixin for the carousel component that has an array passed to it that is used for creating the images using the `each` logic in the answer.

Differing approaches but same result.

Comment: Be sure to mark the answer as accepted if you feel it satisfies what you're looking for. Hope it helps!

Comment: Right, that's what I have now with the inclue_view_original file as a separate component but it's not a block. Maybe that's the issue? It's working as an include, but not putting the images in the right place.

Comment: It doesn't need to be a block as you can just do an include within your block and it will work fine.

The hierarchy if it makes sense would be `extended layout -> content block -> include -> nested mixin` .

You can also have blocks in your mixins if they are ever necessary :)

Comment: Weird because that's exactly the hierarchy I'm using. Check out the working example here and scroll to the bottom. You'll see the image gallery images are not in the right place: http://www.paulrand.design/writing/articles/black-in-the-visual-arts.html

And if you change the extension to .jade, you can see the jade file structure.

Comment: Got it working! 
**In the include file:**  
`.owl-carousel.owl-theme.popup-gallery#owl-carousel-original-article
     -each original in originalImages
      a(href="#{original.link}" title="#{original.title}")
       img(src="#{original.link}")`  
**In the page:**
 `- var originalImages       = [ {link: 'http://placehold.it/800x400', title: 'one'}, {link: 'http://placehold.it/800x500', title: 'two'} ];`

I wish you could put each link on its own line, but I'll deal with it.

Comment: And even better, use the `.push()` syntax to put each array item on its own line. 
`- var originalImages       = []  
 - originalImages.push({link: 'http://placehold.it/800x400', title: 'one'})  
 - originalImages.push({link: 'http://placehold.it/800x500', title: 'two'})`